# cartesian product unbounded number of groups in presto sql

Tags: sql, presto, cartesian-product, trino

Given a table like

```
     Key        |   Value
----------------+-------------
 A              | 1
 A              | 2
 B              | 1
 B              | 2
 C              | 1
 C              | 2
```

How can I generate the product of all `(keys, value)` using `SQL`?

This is the desired output:

```
   Group |   Key        |   Value
---------+--------------+----
 1       |A             | 1
 1       |B             | 1
 1       |C             | 1
 2       |A             | 1
 2       |B             | 1
 2       |C             | 2
 3       |A             | 1
 3       |B             | 2
 3       |C             | 1
 4       |A             | 1
 4       |B             | 2
 4       |C             | 2
 5       |A             | 2
 5       |B             | 2
 5       |C             | 2
 6       |A             | 2
 6       |B             | 1
 6       |C             | 2
 7       |A             | 2
 7       |B             | 2
 7       |C             | 1
 8       |A             | 2
 8       |B             | 1
 8       |C             | 1
```

To illustrate the purpose, I can do this in `Python`, using:

```py
In [1]: from itertools import product
In [2]: list(product([('A',1), ('A', 2)], [('B', 1), ('B', 2)], [('C', 1), ('C', 2)]))
Out[2]:
[(('A', 1), ('B', 1), ('C', 1)),
 (('A', 1), ('B', 1), ('C', 2)),
 (('A', 1), ('B', 2), ('C', 1)),
 (('A', 1), ('B', 2), ('C', 2)),
 (('A', 2), ('B', 1), ('C', 1)),
 (('A', 2), ('B', 1), ('C', 2)),
 (('A', 2), ('B', 2), ('C', 1)),
 (('A', 2), ('B', 2), ('C', 2))]
```

In my real-world application, the number of `(key, value)` pairs is not fixed ahead of time.

Comment: What version of Presto are you using?  Is the number of keys fixed?

Comment: Trino Release 340 (8 Aug 2020). And the number of keys is not fixed, the number of values per key is fixed as 10.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with recursive CTEs -- but it is simpler to put the values into a single column:

```
with recursive kv as (
      select key, value, dense_rank() over (order by key) as seqnum
      from t
     ),
     cte(kv, seqnum) as (
      select array[row(key, value)] as kv, 1 as seqnum
      from kv
      where seqnum = 1
      union all
      select kv || row(kv.key, kv.value), kv.seqnum
      from cte join
           kv
           on kv.seqnum = kv + 1      
     )
select cte.*, row_number() over (order by seqnum)
from cte;
```

You can unnest the array to get separate rows if you like.

Unfortunately, I don't have Presto/Trino on hand to check the syntax.

Comment: running into errors with Presto ```missing column aliases in recursive WITH query
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no straightforward way to do what you're asking, but here's one possible way:

```sql
WITH t(key, value) AS (
    VALUES
     ('A', 1),
     ('A', 2),
     ('B', 1),
     ('B', 2),
     ('C', 1),
     ('C', 2)
),
grouped AS (
   SELECT
       combinations(array_agg(ROW(key, value)), 3) combinations,
       count(distinct key) key_count
   FROM t
),
combinations AS (
    SELECT row_number() OVER () AS "group", combination
    FROM grouped CROSS JOIN UNNEST(combinations) AS u(combination)
    WHERE cardinality(array_distinct(transform(combination, e -> e[1]))) = key_count
),
unnested AS (
    SELECT "group", key, value
    FROM combinations, UNNEST(combination) AS u(key, value)
    ORDER BY "group", "key"
)
SELECT * FROM unnested
```

=>

```
 group | key | value
-------+-----+-------
     1 | A   |     1
     1 | B   |     1
     1 | C   |     1
     2 | A   |     1
     2 | B   |     2
     2 | C   |     1
     3 | A   |     2
     3 | B   |     1
     3 | C   |     1
     4 | A   |     2
     4 | B   |     2
     4 | C   |     1
     5 | A   |     1
     5 | B   |     1
     5 | C   |     2
     6 | A   |     1
     6 | B   |     2
     6 | C   |     2
     7 | A   |     2
     7 | B   |     1
     7 | C   |     2
     8 | A   |     2
     8 | B   |     2
     8 | C   |     2
(24 rows)
```

Here's how it works:

1. Create an array of entries (i.e., `ROW(key, value)`) and count the number of distinct keys overall

- Generate all the possible 3-way combinations from elements of that array using the [`combinations`](https://trino.io/docs/current/functions/array.html#combinations) function. This will produce some "invalid" combinations: those containing the same key multiple times.
- Filter the generated combinations to exclude any combination that doesn't contain all the keys. Assign a group id for each remaining combination using the `row_number` window function.
- Unnest the individual key/value pairs from the combination arrays to produce the output you expect.

Comment: hmmm. so in my setup, the number of keys is not bounded. so I'm not sure if combinations work with that

Comment: less than 15, and the values are also less than 15

Comment: btw, would the recursive CTE help in this context?

Comment: In theory, yes, but recursive CTEs in Trino are not very efficient currently and have a bunch of limitations.